# "Mismatch in datapacket" error in TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tclientdataset

I have a .cds file that suggest it is `TClientDataSet` file. When I try to open it whit `TClientDataSet` in Delphi 7, when set `Active` to `true`, error "Mismatch in datapacket" has occurred. Please help me :(

Comment: Probably it's not a file produced directly by TClientDataSet, or maybe it has been manipulated (compressed, encrypted).

Comment: can you share that file?

Comment: @vavan : You can download this file from http://www.mediafire.com/?zzz4yb9j9sa5di3

Comment: @TOndrej : I don't Know , maybe it has been manipulated or etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded that file and can confirm that it definitely isn't valid CDS file

Answer (score 0):

use the xml mapper tool if you have one and after mapping select all and then from the Create mrnu, DataPacket from XML